# Copy unique row to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets with some sales data. I am trying to sort them so that each customer has a separate sheet(different workbook), and has the item details. I have created a `dictionary` with all customernames.

```
 for name in cust_dict.keys():
     cust_dict[name] = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

 for sheet in sheets:
     ws = sales_wb.sheet_by_name(sheet)
     code = ws.cell(4, 0).value #This is the item code
     df = pd.read_excel(sales_wb, engine='xlrd', sheet_name=sheet, skiprows=7)
     df = df.fillna(0)
     count = 0
     for index,row in df.iterrows():
         print('rotation '+str(count))
         count+=1
         if row['Particulars'] != 0 and row['Particulars'] not in no_cust:
             cust_name = row['Particulars']
        # try:

             cust_dict[cust_name] = cust_dict[cust_name].append(df.loc[df['Particulars'] == cust_name],ignore_index=False)
             cust_dict[cust_name] = cust_dict[cust_name].drop_duplicates()
             cust_dict[cust_name]['Particulars'] = code
```

Right now I have to drop duplicates because the `Particulars` has the client name more than once and hence the cope `appends` the data say x number of times.

I would like to avoid this but I can't seem to figure out a good way to do it.

The second problem is that since the `code` changes to the `code` in the last sheet for all rows, but I want it to remain the same for the rows pulled from a particular sheet.

I can't seem to figure out a way around both the above problems.

Thanks